# how to make sprite change with speed

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Ok so I am new to coding I have a very basic understanding of c# but I am making a brick breaker game / brick buster in my case. But, I have this problem where I need to have the ball sprite change from a my basic white ball to my other sprite after a speed of 10.0f . based what I have seen within tutorials I came up with this code

```
if (ballSpeed > 10f)
    {
      ballImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>("fireball");
     }
```

I don't know if this is even close but any ideas people?

edit: when I go to put Ball ball = new Ball(Content); it brings up a error and it wants me to change it to (content:);

edit2: thanks everyone so far that is trying to help but this isn't working snooks method worked except for the end ( read above edit)

the other guys method is throwing exceptions left and right . any more ideas

Comment: So I have these classes : Ball.cs, Brick.cs, and Paddle.cs
with the ball class do I add the code to the ball.cs or to game2.cs?

Answer (score 1):

You will still have to load the image in the `LoadContent()` or Ball constructor. Because you want the game to have the sprite in its memory before it might potentially be used.

so in the Ball.cs constructor you'll load the sprite.

```
public Ball(ContentManager Content)
{
    textureBall = Content.Load<Texture2D>("fireball"); 
    ...
}
```

You can now choose to do your logic in game2.cs, or you can make a seperate `Draw` method in ball.cs that you can call in your main `Draw`  method (located in game2.cs), which will give you some better [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)). Although you don't really require to in small projects, it's better to learn good habits from the beginning.

So this is how the new method in ball.cs might look.

```
 public void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        ...
        if (ballSpeed > 10.0f)
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(fireball, ballPosition, null, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
        ...
    }
```

Now, if you haven't already, declare the ball gameobject in game2.cs

```
Ball ball = new Ball(Content);
```

Now you can just call `ball.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch)` in the Draw loop of your main game2.cs class. Any logic surrounding the ball will be located in Ball.cs

*The only thing that wasn't clear to me was: "a speed of 10 frames." I think you mean 10.0 float, because measuring speed in frames would be a whole different story. It's better to find a float value for speed that suits your requirements and give the ball a position that way.*

Comment: Ok i thought that F stood for frames :P

Comment: Let me know if this works, If it solved your issue, you can mark my answer as the solution. This will help other people in the future with similar problems.

Comment: so one question what is the textureBall var for I don't see it being used or was that suppose to say fireball?

Comment: here is my project code https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bwgoh9GfyUmieDgtUjY4Mkh2d1U&usp=sharing

Comment: Hello @Snookik I have a problem when I go to put Ball ball = new Ball(Content); it brings up a error  and it wants me to change it to (content:);

Answer (score 1):

Loading content during Draw() or Update() can be quite problematic. The best practice is to load both textures first, and decide which one to draw at runtime

Load both textures in LoadContent()

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    //...
    texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("whiteball");
    fireTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("fireball");
    //...
}
```

Draw different textures in Draw() based on the ball's speed

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    // Draw things before ball ...
    if (ballSpeed > 10f)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(fireTexture, ballPosition, null, Color.White);
    }
    else
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, ballPosition, null, Color.White);
    }
    // Draw the other things...
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

In your case, you should change the constructor of Ball and pass in references to two textures, something like

```
public Ball(Texture2D white, Texture2D fire, Rectangle screenBounds)
{
    // ...
    this.texture = white;
    this.fireTexture = fire;
    // ...
}
```

Of course you need add a field to store the reference

```
Texture2D fireTexture;
```

Comment: ok I will try your method . but could you explain the exception that kept getting thrown when I declare  Ball ball = new Ball(Content); and it wants me to change it to  Ball ball = new Ball(Content:);

Comment: ^^^^^ sorry I keep forgetting the names after my comment

Comment: ok I appreciate your help but its just throwing exceptions left and right

Comment: @ShannessyBrown You really don't need to pass your content manager to the class, if the assets are loaded in your Game's LoadContent().